# Como puedo heredar una variable que obtiene dato con una consulta SQLServer

Tags: c#, poo

Quisiera saber como heredad una variable que contiene el ID de un usuario obtenida con el login para realizar una inserción a la BD con el id del usuario que esta logeado.

Lo he intentado de muchas maneras pero no he resuelto mi problema de herencia.

CLASE PADRE:

```
public class USUARIOS
{
    private string u_;
    private string p_;
    private int id_;

    //public string u { get; set; }
    //public string p { get; set; }
    //public int id { get; set; }

    public string u
    {
        get { return u_; }
        set { u_ = value; }
    }
    public string p
    {
        get { return p_; }
        set { p_ = value; }
    }
    public int id
    {
        get { return id_; }
        set { id_ = value; }
    }
    public USUARIOS()
    {

    }

    public USUARIOS(string no_usu, string pass,ref int i)
    {
        this.u = no_usu;
        this.p = pass;
        this.id = i;
    }

    public void log(string puesto)
    {
        if(puesto=="empleado"){
            MessageBox.Show("Hola Empleado "+u+" "+id);
            SistemaEmpleado pass = new SistemaEmpleado();
            pass.Show();
        }
        else if(puesto=="admin")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hola Admin "+u+" "+id);
            SistemaAdmin pass = new SistemaAdmin();
            pass.Show();
        }
        else 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No se puede acceder");
        }
    }
```

CLASE HIJO

```
public class Empleado : USUARIOS
{
    Conexion x = new Conexion();

    //int i;
    //string name,pass;

    //private string nu;
    //private string ps;
    //private int idd;

    string nu { get; set; }
    string ps { get; set; }
    int idd { get; set; }

    public Empleado(string n, string p,ref int id)
        :base(n,p,ref id)
    {
        //this.nu = n;
        //this.ps = p;
        //this.idd = id;
    }

    public Empleado()
    {

    }
    public Empleado(string u, string p, int id)
    {
        this.nu = u;
        this.ps = p;
        this.idd = id;
    }
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public void add_tck(int id, string equipo, string falla)
    {
        string cadena = "Insert into tickets values ('" + id + "','" + equipo + "','" + falla + "')";
        x.addbd(cadena);
    }
}
```

BOTON PARA HACER INSERCION:

```
    private void iTalk_Button_21_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //string n = "", p="";
        //int i = 0;

        Empleado x = new Empleado();
        USUARIOS u = new USUARIOS();

            DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("              Desea registrar el reporte?", "Confirmacion", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
            if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
            {

            int id = u.id;

            //string equipo = iTalk_ComboBox1.Text;
            //string falla = iTalk_RichTextBox1.Text;
           //int i = u.id;
            x.add_tck(id,iTalk_ComboBox1.Text, iTalk_RichTextBox1.Text);

            }
            else if (result == DialogResult.No)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show("Bye");
                //Close();
            }
    }
```

CLASE DE CONEXION:

```
public class Conexion
{

    //public string ServidorSQL { set; get; }
    //public string BD { set; get; }
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public void datos(ref int id, ref string puesto, ref string nombre, ref string pass)
    {
        string cadena = "select id_u, puesto, nombre, pass from usuarios where nombre='" + nombre + "' and pass='" + pass + "'";

        SqlConnection carretera = new SqlConnection();
        carretera.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=ZBASS-PC\ZBASS;Initial Catalog=sys_tck;Integrated Security=True";
        //carretera.ConnectionString = "data source=" + ServidorSQL + "; initial catalog=" + BD + "; integrated security=true";
        SqlCommand P = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataReader contenedor1;
        try
        {
            carretera.Open();
            P.Connection = carretera;
            P.CommandText = cadena;
            contenedor1 = P.ExecuteReader();
            contenedor1.Read();
            id = contenedor1.GetInt32(0);
            puesto = contenedor1.GetString(1);
            nombre = contenedor1.GetString(2);
            pass = contenedor1.GetString(3);
            carretera.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception t)
        {
            carretera = null;
            MessageBox.Show("Error :" + t.Message);
        }
    }
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public void addbd(string cadena)
    {
        SqlConnection Servicios = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=PCAllINONE;Initial Catalog=sys_tck;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand DB = new SqlCommand();
        try
        {
            Servicios.Open();
            DB.CommandText = cadena;
            DB.Connection = Servicios;
            DB.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Exito, su reporte sera revisado por un administrador.");
            Servicios.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception t)
        {
            Servicios = null;
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + t.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! no entiendo para nada donde esta tu problema de herencia...

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que noto es que creas instancias diferentes de usuario y empleado cuando haces el `new` con lo cual no aplica la herencia, se supone que la instancia debes ser la misma, o estas entendiendo mal el cocepto de herencia.

Con la herencia puedes hacer algo como esto

```
Usuario x = new Emplado();
```

o sea asignar un tipo en una variable de otro.

Si defines la operacion de insert junto a la entidad no deberias asignar parametros en el metodo `add_tck()`

podrias definir

```
public void add_tck(string equipo, string falla)
{
    string cadena = "Insert into tickets values ('" + this.id + "','" + equipo + "','" + falla + "')";
    x.addbd(cadena);
}
```

Se supone que uses

```
Usuario x = new Emplado();
x.log();

x.add_tck(iTalk_ComboBox1.Text, iTalk_RichTextBox1.Text);
```

lo que no observo es donde asignas el id al autenticar en `log()`

Comment: El log() lo hago desde otro formulario, envió los datos de usuario y contraseña

FORMULARIO DE LOG:

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string u = txt_usu.Text;
            string p = txt_pass.Text;
            string pue = "";
            int id = 0;

            Conexion x = new Conexion();
            x.datos(ref id,ref pue, ref u, ref p);

            USUARIOS a = new USUARIOS(u,p,ref id);
            a.log(pue);
        }

x.datos() muestra los datos en la clase USUARIOS, pero quisiera heredar ese id en la clase Empleado

Comment: Realmente estoy confundido con el tema de herencia.

Comment: Pero leiste algo al respecto para tener en claro que es la herencia? algo como ser: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/inheritance

Comment: claro, pero si lo haces desde otro formulario esa instancia que haces con el "new" de USUARIOS solo aplica mientras estes en ese form, si cambias veo que creas una neuva instancia, lo que planteas no es herencia, sino que deberias persistir los datos y volver a recuperarlos en el otro form, o sin pasar la instancia de usuario de un form a otro